# safari adding padding to table cell

Tags: css, safari, tablecell

I have a nav menu made using a table with links inside. On chrome and all other browsers, the td elements have no padding, and the inside links can have padding and fill up the whole td element. On Safari there is an added top and bottom padding that is throwing off the spacing of the inner links. How do I remove this extra padding in safari?

html-

```
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Link 1</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 2</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 3</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 4</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 5</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 6</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 7</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 8</a></td>
          <td><a href="">Link 9</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css(scss) -

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-width: 1100px;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

nav {
  background: $modBg;
  border: 1px solid $border;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
   table {
     width: 100%;
     tr {
       td {
         text-align: center;
         a {
           padding: 15px;
           display: inline-block;
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and some images showing the difference-

[image: table cell on safari]

Here's a jsfiddle replicating the problem- https://jsfiddle.net/davmex/m4ea9gLr/

Comment: I'm looking at it in Safari and Chrome on Mac and it looks the same. https://jsfiddle.net/6k4gfk00/. Can you create a fiddle where it's different?  Which version of Safari are you using?  Are you using a reset css?

Comment: I figured out why your fiddle was different, all my styles have box-sizing: border-box, when I added that it replicated my problem, I'll add a link in my description

Comment: What version of Safari are you on?  Your fiddle looks identical in both to me.

Comment: I'm using Browserstack to test it on safari 10.1, I also have a colleague with a mac that confirmed the bug on his macbook.

Comment: Can't replicate anymore on Safari Version 16.5 (17615.2.9.11.6, 17615)